# How to: JTable look and feel like Windows 7 Details View or Vuze table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rendering

In Windows 7 if we set the content of a Folder in Details view, then it turns into a table like structure, in which if we hover a row it renders a rectangular shape with light blue color and slightly curvy corner on that row and if we select a row a similar shape with blue color set on that row. This similar effect is shown by [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/)'s table.

Is there any way to achieve this table rendering for JTable? If so what is the way to get it?

Any information will be helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

The highlighted portions in the following image shows what I intended to achieve. The first highlight is the selected row and the second one is hovered.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that by implement [Substance Custom Look and Feel](https://github.com/Insubstantial) for JTreeTable,

- plugin for [SwingX](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/swinglabs/swingx-163-has-been-released)
- [TreeTable by aepryh](http://aephyr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) (best and open code for TreeTable)

notice you have to change `XxxRenderer`  to `SubstanceXxxRenderer` (works on Xp / Win7 / 2008R2)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built-in to achieve this. You can achieve the hover effect by using custom cell renderers and mouseover listeners. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3771394/143585) answer gives you an overall picture of what to do.

As for the rectangular effect, again - custom cell renderers only, with either images, or [drawRoundRect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRoundRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed this post. JIDE has a component that does what you need. It is in paid JIDE Grids product. You can find a screenshot at http://www.jidesoft.com/images/navigation-components.png. Of course you can do this by yourself by overriding the paintComponent of a regular JTable. Using cell renderer approach won't work as the rollover effect needs to span the whole row.